# Codeigniter- Exporting to CSV Issues

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am struck with exporting data from database using codeigniter. Help is much appreciated.

This is my view code for this issue.

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('admin/consignment1/test_con'),  
$hiddenFields, 'class="form-horizontal"');  ?>

<td><input type="submit" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['Con_No']; ?>" 
class="btn btn-info pull-left"> </td>
```

Controller

```
public function test_con(){
    $var= $this->input->post('id');
    $data['get_con_by'] = $this->consignment_model->get_con_by($var);
    $data['view']='admin/consignment1/con_table';
    $this->load->view('admin/layout', $data);
}
```

Model

```
public function get_con_by($var){

    $this->db->from('consignment');
    $this->db->where('Con_No',$var);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

There is no issue with displays the data on my view. When i try to export data from model using other function, i get my CSV with empty data. here is my function on controller for same model.

```
public function exportCSV(){
    // file name

    $filename = 'Con_'.date('Ymd').'.csv';
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/csv; ");

    // get data
    $usersData = $this->consignment_model->get_con_by($var);

    // file creation
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $header = array("ste","Name","Gender","Email");
    fputcsv($file, $header);
    foreach ($usersData as $key=>$line){
        fputcsv($file,$line);
    }
    fclose($file);
    exit;
}
```

I have another model

```
public function get_all_pins(){
    $query = $this->db->get('consignment');
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

I have not problem with exporting to CSV

The difference between both scnerio is

```
$usersData = $this->consignment_model->get_con_by($var); // Not working

$usersData = $this->consignment_model->get_all_pins(); // working one.
```

Can you help me how to solve this.

Comment: Is it, that in `test_con()` your getting $var with `$var= $this->input->post('id');`. But you're not assigning $var in `exportCSV()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the answer to your query, check in the query that gets generated using

```
$this->db->last_query()
```

Check in the query that got generated. Is it the same you expecting or it have any issue? You may cross verify the output for the same query in phpmyadmin.

The only issue i foresee here is the query being generated dose not return any data  / output or it might have an error in executing the query. The second is less expected. But debugging the same this way will help you reach to your actual issue / problem.